# YouTube update enforcement bypass? +Reasons why the old YouTube app is superior

Tags: applications, youtube, downgrade, search, material-design

The time bomb of YouTube's legacy versions has exploded:
**The *“later”* button to postpone the update has disappeared.** YouTube is copying WhatsApp's update mesh.

I really wish to keep using a legacy version of YouTube's Android application, but now, YouTube has pulled the plugs by **hiding the “update later” button.**

#### Why have they disabled it in first place?

The application would probably still work technically.

### Advantages of YouTube's legacy versions:

- **Unlimited search history.**
- Exiting search does not require to reload the results of the previous search or viewed channel/playlist/feed/etc., which saves time and occasionally mobile data.
- I still had search terms from 2015 because I never updated. Search history with capitalization saved.
- Profile pictures with the shape of a square. Superior field of view.
- Less minimalism, more border lines. (I personally dislike
  minimalism.)

  - [Free from material design.](http://blog.usabilla.com/flat-design-going-far/) (I do not hate material design,
    but the rounded corners look loose. Windows 10's flat design is OK
    becaubecause it looks still very angular. Although, I like the ripple
    animation of mterial design.).
- Full numbers instead of rounded numbers (YouTube calls them “abbreviated numbers”. Toxic minimalism) for ratings, view counts and suscriber counts. **Rounded numbers** are too shallow. (*“2M”* looks shallow, while e.g. the number “*2.021.435*” looks vibrant and ultimately *sexier* than a digit with one letter behind it. Additionally, “2B” can be confused with 28 on the first sight, while a a long number such as 2.039.721.486 looks truly unmistakenably immersive.).
- Ability to pre-open videos from loaded search results before Internet connection has been established, so that I do not need to open it **when** the connection has established.
- Ability to pre-open search pages too. Pre-opening searches saves the search query into the search history, so that I do not forget searching it the next time I open YouTube's app. Like a tiny sticky note.

#### How do I keep using the legacy versions of YouTube?

I know MixerBox, but MixerBox has no search history and multi/pop-up window support.

Answer (score 1):

Google services framework does this. if you disable it, you get YouTube back, but google play can't load.