# How to back up app data from system applications? (e.g. YouTube search history)

Tags: applications, adb, backup, bootloader, youtube

In 2018, YouTube triggered their [kill switch / time bomb for older versions of their Android application.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/196342/youtube-update-enforcement-bypass-reasons-why-the-old-youtube-app-is-superior)

Their more recent versions of their app limits the search history to 50 items, which means that after updating, the entire unlimited search history of 1000+ items will be erased except for the last 50 searches. Trivia: Capital letters get set to small letters.

The device is a few years old already and the bootloader was not unlocked right after purchase. **Remember: Always unlock bootloader after purchasing the device. Otherways: regret.** That bootloader has been a headache to me repeatedly.

It is possible to back up some apps using ADB, but YouTube is a system app.

#### How can I back up the app data of Android system apps despite locked bootloader?

If there is a way to bypass the w*** (**pe) during bootloader unlock without losing data, that would be good.

My goal is to rescue the search history that got trapped in the older version of the YouTube app due to [Google's time bomb that made the app inaccessible.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaUAIPKdzls)

It is not **that** important, but if there is any possible way I could rescue that search history, that would be appreciated. Otherways, I would just move on, but I would like to give it a try.

Comment: All youtube search history is stored on your Google account, the newer versions of the app might show only the last 50 entries, but every single search you've made is in your account's data except if you've opted out of it in the privacy settings.

Comment: @NickDeltaIn the beginning, I was not logged in. These searches are only saved in this trapped, timebombed YouTube app.